# Vim ex knowing number typed before

Tags: perl, vim, shortcut, ex

I'm making a shortcut that places a # at the front of each line, in the next *x* lines. *x* is a number I type before entering the shortcut, like typing `11dd` deletes the next eleven lines.

The command is `.,+10 s/^/#/g`. Here the number ten should really be whatever was typed before the shortcut. How do I make the shortcut change according to the number that was typed before it?

Added after question was answered:

So now I have the following in the .vimrc:

```
nmap c1 :s/^/#/g<esc>``
nmap c0 :s/^#//g<esc>``
```

Which allows me to type `13ac`, to add `#` at the front of the next 13 lines, and `13dc` to delete any `#` at the front of the next 13 lines.

It's better than `=pod` and `=cut` for they cause errors when nested.
c1=comment add,
c0=comment delete.
# is used in Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ex` mode, you can use the following command:

```
s/^/#/count
```

where `count` is the number of lines you want to change. You can't put the number before the command, because that is used to select the starting line (current line if omitted). Thus:

```
5s/^/#/3
```

will add a '#' before lines 5, 6 and 7.

#### Edit

In `ex` mode you can use the `map` command to create a shortcut to a colon command, which you can then use with a prefix number:

```
map CC :s/^/#/g
```

Now you can use 'xCC' in `vi` mode to prepend '#' to the next `x` lines.

Comment: but i mean, isn't there some sort of ex/vimscript variable or something that gets filled whenever a number gets typed?
somehow vim knows what got typed before dd when one presses 11dd.

Comment: @Hermann Ingjaldsson there is a v:count variable, but it is for more complex cases.